# Como passar informação de um ficheiro para um vetor dinâmico de estruturas em C?

Tags: c, array, arquivo, programação-dinâmica

Boa tarde!  (EDITADO)
Estou a fazer um trabalho em linguagem `C`, onde tenho de mostrar na consola a informação guardada num ficheiro de texto, mas é obrigatório passar toda a informação para `vetores` dinâmicos de estruturas.
Eu penso já ter conseguido feito alguma coisa, mas quando tento guardar a especialidade numa `variável`, o ficheiro acaba por guardar as palavras seguintes.

Ex: O `v->nome` está a guardar "Joao Silva" e o `v->especialidade` está a guardar "Neurologia    9.30 - 17.00" e eu pretendo guardar apenas "Neurologia".
Alguém me consegue ajudar?

```
struct hora_entrada { int horas, minutos; };

struct hora_saida {int horas, minutos; };

typedef struct medico med, *p_med;
struct medico {
  char nome[ST_TAM];
  char especialidade[ST_TAM];
  struct hora_entrada h_e;
  struct hora_saida h_s;
};

int le_dados () {

  FILE *f, *g;
  med *v;

  f = fopen("medico.txt", "rt");
  g = fopen("paciente.txt", "rt");
  if (f == NULL || g == NULL) {
    printf("Erro no acesso ao ficheiro.\n");
    return 0;
  }

v = malloc(sizeof(med));
if (v == NULL) {
  printf("Erro na alocaçao de memoria.\n");
  return 0;
}

while ((fscanf(f,"%49[^\n] %49[^\n]",v->nome, v->especialidade)) == 2)
  printf("%s\n%s",v->nome, v->especialidade);

fclose(f);
```

}

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas o `fscanf` era para ler o primeiro e o ultimo nome apenas ? E no caso em que tem mais do que 2 nomes como em `Ana Maria Santos` ?  Para ler apenas o primeiro nome um `%s` é suficiente.

Comment: Eu pretendo ler o ficheiro todo e guardar cada palavra numa variável da estrutura.
Neste caso quero guardar "Joao" numa variavel, "Silva" noutra, "Neurologia" noutra e assim adiante...

Comment: Mas a estrutura tem `nome_p` e `nome_s` e o ficheiro tem medicos com 3 nomes, como é que isso vai funcionar?

Comment: Tens razão, ainda não me tinha apercebido disso... então tenho de guardar o nome todo numa variavel e os restantes em variaveis individuais. Sabes como se faz?

Comment: Sim, está guardando não apenas a especialidade porque seu comando de leitura (scanf) está definindo para ler até o final da linha (ou ao completar 49 caracteres). Repense a especificação de formato de seu scanf. Se o nome da especialidade for sempre uma única palavra então utilize apenas um %s, se o nome da especialidade puder conter espaços então especifique o tamanho máximo que, me parece, ser 15 e não 49.

Answer (score 0):

Eu prefiro usar fgets em vez de scanf para ler linhas de um arquivo (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917550/difference-between-fgets-and-fscanf).

```
while (fgets(v->nome, 49, f)){
        fgets(v->especialidade, 49, f);
        fgets(aux, 49, f); // Lê os horários //
        printf("%s%s", v->nome, v->especialidade);
}
```

Tu pode ler o nome e especialidade com fgets e os horários com fscanf, se você preferir.